# TypeError: ping is not a function

Tags: javascript

Im trying to make a discord bot that shows my minecraft server stats and stuff. It is almost done but when i do the command it comes up with this in the terminal: TypeError: ping is not a function. Here is my code:

```
const {Client, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js')
 
const bot = new Client()
 
const ping = require('minecraft-server-util')
 
const token = 'not gunna tell u my token'

const ip = 'or ip'
 
const PREFIX = '!'
 
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log('Bot has come online.')
})
 
bot.on('message', message =>{
 
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ')
 
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'mc':
 
            ping(ip, parseInt(25565), (error, reponse) =>{
                if(error) throw error
                const Embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setTitle('Server Status')
                .addField('Server IP', reponse.host)
                .addField('Server Version', reponse.version)
                .addField('Online Players', reponse.onlinePlayers)
                .addField('Max Players', reponse.maxPlayers)
                
                message.channel.send(Embed)
            })
        break
 
    }
 
})
 
bot.login(token)
```

Comment: Compare the `require` and `ping` calls with how they’re used in the example https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-util#pingstatus

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs say](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-util), `ping` is a *property* of that module's exports: it's not the whole export:

```
const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
util.ping('play.hypixel.net', { port: 25565 })
```

For your code, either destructure out the `ping` property on import:

```
const { ping } = require('minecraft-server-util')
```

Or give it some other name, then call `.ping` on the imported object:

```
const util = require('minecraft-server-util');

// ...

util.ping(ip, /* etc */
```

Also, if you want the port to be the default 25565, there's no need to pass it at all. The module also returns a Promise, which you should use instead of the callback form:

```
ping(ip)
  .then((response) => {
    // handle response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // handle errors
  });
```

Comment: new error from ur suggestion: Expected 'options' to be an object or undefined, got number

Comment: If you were intending to pass a port there, use `{ port: somePortNumber }` (don't use `parseInt`, just use a number literal). The port defaults to 25565, so there's no need to pass a port at all if that's the port you want.

Comment: ill post my new code as an answer, but i still got the same error

Comment: The docs say that the port you're trying to use is already the default port, so there's no need to pass it. Have you tried the Promise version? Should be as simple as `ping(ip)
  .then((response) => {
    // handle response
  })`